# need to get template from ng-init function call of controller for the custom directive in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-template, angularjs-templates

As beginner to angularjs directives I am confused little bit. Can any one help me in the following. The following is my custom directive.

```
app.directive('customCharts', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            dashboard1Data: '=',
            title1Text: '=',
            dashboard2Data: '=',
            title2Text: '=',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var template = '<div class="col1"> <p class="graphtitle"> {{title1Text}}</p>  <c3-simple id="dashboard1Data" config="dashboard1Data"></c3-simple> </div>' + ' <div class="col2"> <p class="graphtitle"> {{title2Text}}</p>  <c3-simple id="dashboard2Data" config="dashboard2Data"></c3-simple> </div> ';

            var parent = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.customChartsDiv')) // DOM element where the compiled template can be appended
            var linkFn = $compile(template);
            var content = linkFn(scope);
            parent.append(content);   
         }
    }
 }]);
```

I want my template to be as `template = templateFromController`. i.e., I don't want  to hard code my template in the directive. Rather I would like to form the template in the controller during ng-init function call and I want my directive to use that template. How can I do it?

So in my controller, I would be having some thing like,

```
var templateFromController = '<div class="col1"> <p class="graphtitle"> {{title1Text}}</p>  <c3-simple id="dashboard1Data" config="dashboard1Data"></c3-simple> </div>'
             +' <div class="col2"> <p class="graphtitle"> {{title2Text}}</p>  <c3-simple id="dashboard2Data" config="dashboard2Data"></c3-simple> </div> '       
             +  '<div class="col1"> <p class="graphtitle"> {{title3Text}}</p>  <c3-simple id="dashboard3Data" config="dashboard3Data"></c3-simple> </div>'
             +' <div class="col2"> <p class="graphtitle"> {{title3Text}}</p>  <c3-simple id="dashboard4Data" config="dashboard4Data"></c3-simple> </div> ';
```

or

```
var templateFromController = '<div class="col1"> <p class="graphtitle"> {{title1Text}}</p>  <c3-simple id="dashboard1Data" config="dashboard1Data"></c3-simple> </div>'
         +' <div class="col2"> <p class="graphtitle"> {{title2Text}}</p>  <c3-simple id="dashboard2Data" config="dashboard2Data"></c3-simple> </div> ';
```

Something like this, based on some other criteria in my ng-init function call of controller I will form my `var templateFromController`, and I want my custom directive to use this templateFromController for its template. Can any one help me to do it?

@Daniel, I made the following changes as per your suggestion :

```
app.directive('customCharts', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            dashboard1Data: '=',
            title1Text: '=',
            dashboard2Data: '=',
            title2Text: '=',
            template: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var parent = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.customChartsDiv')) // DOM element where the compiled template can be appended
            var linkFn = $compile(template);
            var content = linkFn(scope);
            parent.append(content);
        }
    }

}]);
```

And in controller :

```
var template = '<div> </div>';    
$scope.init = function() {  
    template = '<div class="col1"> <p class="graphtitle"> {{title1Text}}</p>  <c3-simple id="dashboard1Data" config="dashboard1Data"></c3-simple> </div>';
    }
```

And in my jsp, I have :

```
<div class="customChartsDiv">
    <div custom-charts dashboard1-data="dashboard1Data" title1-text="title1Text" dashboard2-data="dashboard2Data" title2-text="title2Text" template="template"></div>
</div>
```

But it is giving error : template is not defined at line `var linkFn = $compile(template);` of my directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define it as an attribute on your directive and then pass in the object/string (that's created in your controller).

```
app.directive('customCharts', ['$compile', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
        dashboard1Data: '=',
        title1Text: '=',
        dashboard2Data: '=',
        title2Text: '=',
        template: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var parent =   angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.customChartsDiv')) // DOM element      where the compiled template can be appended
        var linkFn = $compile(scope.template);
        var content = linkFn(scope);
        parent.html('').append(content); 
     }
   }
}]);
```

Here is a plnkr that shows this should work: http://embed.plnkr.co/O6gNn1b6C7xJ3y2jJC05/preview

Comment: I am getting an error template is not defined at line var linkFn = $compile(template); of my directive. please notice, I have edited the question with your suggested solution. Any resolution for this error ... ?

Comment: Thanks Daniel but I have come across another small problem with this. Please find my plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/s0HiYk907TQLB0SAhMwY?p=preview. I am changing the template after button click but it is not reflecting in my directive, still it is showing test only, I have used watch too.

Comment: In the `scope.$watch` function it should be just `template` not `scope.template`

Comment: I have updated the plunker and is working fine but the problem here is still the old template result remaining as it is. i.e.,  both test and test is changed are appearing upon button click.  When I click button only the new template should present, any fix for this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: In your click function clear the HTML content of customChartsDiv before applying the new template to $scope.template `angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.customChartsDiv')).html('');`
http://plnkr.co/edit/e2z9EnrcyKmBfAG1pCKH?p=preview

Comment: I came to know doing DOM manipulation in controller is not a good practice. Instead angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.customChartsDiv')).html(''); doing in controller, is there any better alternative for clean recompilation?